# What am I doing here wrong?

Tags: java

The initial output of the texfile is this. **NO ARRAYLIST OR COMPARATOR IS ALLOWED**:

```
Steve Jobs 9 f 91
Bill Gates 6 m 90
James Gosling 3 m 100
James Gosling 3 f 100
Dennis Ritchie 5 m 94
Steve Jobs 9 m 95
Dennis Ritchie 5 f 100
Jeff Dean 7 m 100
Bill Gates 6 f 96
Jeff Dean 7 f 100
Sergey Brin 27 f 97
Sergey Brin 22 m 98
```

The **collateExams** method collates/sorts exam objects starting with the first 'm' (midterm) of the first object and immediately followed by the same person's 'f'(final). Only a **SINGLE loop construct** is allowed. The output from collateExams() should be the one below but my code is not working, i.e. collateExams method is not working. Could smb help me with that? The output from collateExams() should be

```
Bill Gates 6 m 90
Bill Gates 6 f 96
James Gosling 3 m 100
James Gosling 3 f 100
Dennis Ritchie 5 m 94
Dennis Ritchie 5 f 100
Steve Jobs 9 m 95
Steve Jobs 9 f 91
Jeff Dean 7 m 100
Jeff Dean 7 f 100
Sergey Brin 22 m 98
Sergey Brin 27 f 97
```

Im getting NullExceptions at

```
r[2*position[exams[i].getID()]+1] = new Exam(r[i].getFirstName(), r[i].getLastName(), r[i].getID(), r[i].getExamType(), r[i].getScore());

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

class P2 {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        Scanner data = new Scanner(new File("Exam.txt"));
        Exam[] readObjects = readAllExams(data);
        Exam[] collateObjects = collateExams(readObjects);

        System.out.println("1) Initially the list of exams of students is: ");
        System.out.println();
        for(int i = 0; i < readObjects.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(readObjects[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Sorted list: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < collateObjects.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(collateObjects[i]);
        }
    }



    public static Exam[] readAllExams(Scanner s) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    {

        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";
        int ID = 0;
        String examType = "";
        char examTypeCasted;
        int score = 0;

        int index = 0;

        Exam[] object = new Exam[s.nextInt()];

        while(s.hasNext())
        {
            //Returns firtsName and lastName 
            firstName = s.next();
            lastName = s.next();

            //Returns ID number
            if(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                ID = s.nextInt();
            }
            else 
                s.next();

            //Returns examType which is 'M' or 'F'
            examType = s.next();
            examTypeCasted = examType.charAt(0);

            if(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                score = s.nextInt();
            }
            //Exam[] object = new Exam[s.nextInt()];

            object[index] = new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examTypeCasted, score);
            //System.out.println();
            index++;
        }
        readExam(s);
        return object;


    }

    public static Exam readExam(Scanner s)
    {
        String firstName = "";
        String lastName = "";
        int ID = 0;
        String examType = "";
        char examTypeCasted = 0;
        int score = 0;

        while (s.hasNext())
        {
            //Returns firtsName and lastName 
            firstName = s.next();
            lastName = s.next();

            //Returns ID number
            if(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                ID = s.nextInt();
            }
            //Returns examType which is 'M' or 'F'
            examType = s.next();
            examTypeCasted = examType.charAt(0);

            if(s.hasNextInt())
            {
                score = s.nextInt();
            }

        }
        Exam temp = new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examTypeCasted, score);
        return temp;
    }

    public static Exam[] collateExams(Exam[] exams)
    {

        Exam[] r = new Exam[exams.length]; 
        int [] position = new int[exams.length];
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0;  (i < exams.length) && (i < position.length); i++)
        {
            position[i] = -1;
            if(exams[i].getExamType()=='m')
               {
                   if(position[exams[i].getID()]==-1)
                   {
                       r[index*2] = new Exam(r[i].getFirstName(), r[i].getLastName(), r[i].getID(), r[i].getExamType(), r[i].getScore());

                       position[exams[i].getID()] = 2*index;

                   }
                   else
                       r[2*position[exams[i].getID()] - 1] = new Exam(r[i].getFirstName(), r[i].getLastName(), r[i].getID(), r[i].getExamType(), r[i].getScore());
               }
            else
               {
                   if(position[exams[i].getID()]==-1)
                   {
                       r[index*2+1] = new Exam(r[i].getFirstName(), r[i].getLastName(), r[i].getID(), r[i].getExamType(), r[i].getScore());
                       position[exams[i].getID()] = 2*index+1;
                   }

                  else    
                      r[2*position[exams[i].getID()]+1] = new Exam(r[i].getFirstName(), r[i].getLastName(), r[i].getID(), r[i].getExamType(), r[i].getScore());
               }
               index++;

            }

            return r;
    }
}
```

Comment: Joshua, go look at your other post on this topic, I have added some cleaned up code that may get you to a better spot.

Comment: Thanks @Michael, but only SINGLE loop construct is allowed!

Comment: The post I replied to said nothing about that.  So, you are only allowed a single loop construct, for the sorting only I assume?  Are maps allowed?  Any other restrictions?

Comment: @Michael, sorry for the previous post for not specifying specs.. and yes, only one loop and only inside one method, no maps, no arraylists, no comparators.

Comment: What's wrong with `ArrayList` and `Comparator`?

Comment: Im not allowed to use them

Comment: It sounds like this is a homework assignment so he has limits.  Also sounds like a complete kluge solution :)

Comment: @Michael, it's a project. I'm having trouble with the collateExams method

Answer (score 0):

This is absolute and complete kluge, but it meets your criteria.  If this doesn't work for you then you would have to look at object creation or something else to fit your needs.

```
static int maxId = 0;

public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{

    Scanner data = new Scanner(Answer28522397.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("exams.txt"));
    Exam[] readObjects = readAllExams(data);

    System.out.println("1) Initially the list of exams of students is: ");
    System.out.println();
    for(int i = 0; i < readObjects.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(readObjects[i]);
    }

    Object[][] collatedObjects = collateExams(readObjects);

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Sorted list: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < collatedObjects.length; i++)
    {
        if (collatedObjects[i][0] != null && collatedObjects[i][1] != null)
        {
            System.out.println(collatedObjects[i][0]);
            System.out.println(collatedObjects[i][1]);
        }
    }
}

public static Exam[] readAllExams(Scanner s) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
{
    int index = 0;
    Exam[] object = new Exam[s.nextInt()];

    while(s.hasNext())
    {
        Exam e = readExam(s);
        maxId = e.getID() > maxId ? e.getID() : maxId;
        object[index] = e;
        index++;
    }

    return object;
}

public static Exam readExam(Scanner s)
{
    String firstName = "";
    String lastName = "";
    int ID = 0;
    String examType = "";
    char examTypeCasted = 0;
    int score = 0;

    //Returns firtsName and lastName 
    firstName = s.next();
    lastName = s.next();

    //Returns ID number
    if(s.hasNextInt())
    {
        ID = s.nextInt();
    }
    //Returns examType which is 'M' or 'F'
    examType = s.next();
    examTypeCasted = examType.charAt(0);

    if(s.hasNextInt())
    {
        score = s.nextInt();
    }

    return new Exam(firstName, lastName, ID, examTypeCasted, score);
}

public static Object[][] collateExams(Exam[] exams)
{
    Exam [] r = new Exam[exams.length];
    System.arraycopy(exams, 0, r, 0, exams.length); 


    Object[][] collation = new Object[maxId+1][2];

    for(Exam exam : exams)
    {
       if (exam.getExamType() == 'm')
       {
           collation[exam.getID()][0] = exam;
       }
       else
       {
           collation[exam.getID()][1] = exam;
       }           
    }

    return collation;
}
```